# C#: How to make a class variable persistent

Tags: c#

In my C# codebehind file(.cs), I have just one class and it is derived from System.Web.UI.Page. The class contains array of dictionaries. On one of the button clicks i.e. in the button click event handler function, I create object of this class and do something. Now, on another button click, I need to do something else which needs data belonging to the object or instance of the class created on previous button click. How can I achieve this?  I need all the data especially array of dictionaries belonging to that object/class instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTTP is stateless**. So there is no direct way to do this.

What you can do is keep this in some storage mechanism and access it later. You may consider DB `table`, `Session` etc...

Here is an example to store in `Session`

```
 YourClass object1=new YourClass();
 object1.SomeProperty="HTTP is stateless"; 
 Session["ThatObject"]=object1;
```

You can access this in the next button click event like this

```
 if(Session["ThatObject"]!=null)
 {
   YourClass object1=(YourClass) Session["ThatObject"];
   //now you can access object1 properties here.
 }
```

It is not a good idea to store **so many** items in session as it will make your server cry since sessions stored in server.

Comment: Thanks Shyju. That worked perfectly. But now I am facing another problem. On the first button click, I basically create a html table dynamically. The table contains some checkboxes too. Now once the table is rendered, user can select one or many of these checkboxes. The problem is, after page reload i.e. after clicking on second button, I am not able to figure out which checkbox was set. This is because I store the class variable in session just after rendering the table. So, in session variable all checkboxes are unchecked always. Any solutions? How can I store these checkboxes' states too?

Comment: @user1465266 You may use ajax to make a server page and update the values from your storage (Session variable)

Comment: So you mean I need to use ajax to update the values stored in my session variable? Sorry but I am kind of new to .net and other web technologies. Could you please elaborate? Thanks...

Comment: yes. you can use ajax to make a call to a server page where you access the session variable and update it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *static* declaration so that it stays persisted across requests.

```
static IDictionary<string,object> myPersistentDict;
```

Of course, you have to worry about thread safety with this approach.  If you're using .NET 4, there's a built in dictionary class that handles this for you, [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx)

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> myPersistentDict;
```